# PhotoCapture in Unity + Hololens emulator taking weird photos

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens-emulator

I'm trying to use PhotoCapture in Unity with Hololens emulator, but everytime that I generate a photo from the camera I get this:

[image]

I already tested the webcam in Windows and it takes normal photos; this happens even if I use PhotoCapture in a Unity app or if just use the camera in the Hololens emulator. My graphic card is an NVidia Geforce GTX 1060 just in case.

Thanks!

Comment: could you add the code of how you get the capture?

Comment: I had something similar happen to me before and it was an NVidia graphics card setting that was causing the issue.  I don't recall offhand the exact setting but to fix I reset all options back to factory/default and the issue went away.  Must've been something I had changed while messing around with settings.

Comment: I haven't changed anything in the graphic card settings @slaphshot33324, I did some additional search on the web, and there is people saying that the Hololens emulator does not support using the webcam in the pc, which makes sense since it works in Unity just fine.

Comment: I answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55861060/web-cam-support-in-hololens-emulator/55917170#55917170