# Web Cam support in Hololens Emulator

Tags: webcam, hololens-emulator, windows-mixed-reality

Can laptop's web camera used in the latest Hololens emulator ?

I'm following this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mr-azure-302 to integrate MS Computer Vision API into Hololens.

I want to test this in the Hololens emulator before moving to the device. So, Will I be able to enable Web Cam for recognizing objects using vision API.I'm using Hololens Emulator 10.0 version.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is No. HL has own cameras, not compatible with a webcam.

Update. For the case, I would recommend creating video processing library and test it in simple desktop application.

Comment: Why incompatible? HL1 video capture uses the same API as web cameras.

Comment: The question was about connecting an external cam to the emulator not about getting data from cam. The emulator doesn't allow to connect external devices.

Comment: Perhaps it’s correct in part of external devices, but the wording is still confusing. HL camera is quite a webcam in terms of accessing it via API, it’s just emulator that might be unable to use host’s web camera as a substitution.

Comment: It would be good, if emulator is able to use the host's web camera. So that before connecting to HL device, it can be tested thoroughly

Comment: Sorry, it's technically impossible.